# Problem with shortcut key "Super+T" in 13.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, dolphin

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 with Unity. I set `Dolphin` is default file manager. When I open trash via shortcut key <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, I receive error: `Malformed URL trash://`.

Comment: Try deleting all files in `~/.local/share/Trash folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your `~/.local` to `~/.local_bak`
Then logout and log back in.

***Courtesy:*** http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,108458.msg927709.html#msg927709

N.B: `~` refers to your home directory.

Comment: @VietNguyen, You're welcome.. :)